# How to add docker container as data source in grafana?

Tags: linux, postgresql, docker, grafana

I have a Postgres Database which was deployed as a Docker container in Linux server. How can i add this as a data source in grafana? I tried finding the docker host IP address using sudo ip addr show docker0 and got the result as 172.17.255.255. I added this URL in Host name field. And added the port number as 5432. But still, grafana is unable to fetch the data from DB. How can i do this?

Comment: (That address looks like the broadcast address for the 172.17.0.0/16 network.  If this is a programming-related question, can you edit the question to include any relevant source code?  This seems more like a question about configuring an administration tool, which might not be on-topic for Stack Overflow.)

Answer (score 0):

If your database has its port closed you should use a docker networks but if the port is exposed you should try to use your host ip address instead of the docker gateway address

Comment: Thanks for the input Gwilherm. Can you please explain what do you exactly mean by Docker networks ? And also, as you said to use host IP address, so As the container is in LINUX server, will it be my Linux sever's IP address ?

Comment: Yeah it will be your server ip address
docker networks is a way to link different containers, here is a tutorial: https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/

Answer (score 0):

1. With `docker ps`, check if your Postgres container expose the port, eg.

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE            COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                       NAMES
e25459aa0ed6   postgres:10.17   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   12 seconds ago   Up 11 seconds   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp, :::5432->5432/tcp   jovial_merkle
```

2. If not, stop the service, then restart it exposing the port with `docker run -d -p 5432:5432 ....`
3. Check if there is any firewall rule that allow to access the port from outside the server.
4. Now you can reach you DB using the server IP